# Next odd number in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

To find the next odd number for an input the following code is being used:

```
a=5.4; // Input
b=Math.ceil(a); // Required to turn input to whole number 
b=b+(((b % 2)-1)*-1); // Gives 7
```

The ceil rounding function is required.

Is this safe and is there a more compact way to do this?

**EDIT**: When the input is already an odd whole number then nothing happens. For example 5.0 will return 5

Comment: How about `5.0`? What do you expect as next odd number?

Comment: @VisioN The same number. 5.0 -> 5 (updated question) thanks.

Comment: `b = Math.ceil(a) | 1;` would be the most compact, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer And thats the answer I was really looking for. It includes the Math.ceil call! If you submit your comment as an answer I'll switch the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the question author's request:

The most compact way to achieve it is

```
b = Math.ceil(a) | 1;
```

First use `ceil()` to obtain the smallest integer not smaller than `a`, then obtain the smallest odd integer not smaller than `ceil(a)` by doing a bitwise or with 1 to ensure the last bit is set without changing anything else.

To obtain the smallest odd integer strictly larger than `a`, use

```
b = Math.floor(a+1) | 1;
```

#### Caveats:

Bit-operators operate on signed 32-bit integers in Javascript, so the value of `a` must be smaller than or equal to `2^31-1`, resp. strictly smaller for the second. Also, `a` must be larger than `-2^31-1`.

If the representation of signed integers is not two's complement, but ones' complement or sign-and-magnitude (I don't know whether Javascript allows that, Java doesn't, but it's a possibility in C), the value of `a` must be larger than `-1` -- the result of `Math.ceil(a)` resp. `Math.floor(a+1)` must be nonnegative.

Answer (score 16):

How about just

```
b += b % 2 ^ 1;
```

The remainder after dividing by 2 will always be 0 or 1, so the `^` operator (exclusive-OR) flips it to the opposite.

(Also, `(b & 1) ^ 1` would work too. Oh, I guess `b = b ^ 1` would work for positive integers, but it'd be problematic for big integers.)

Comment: Huh? @Esailija if `b` is zero, the next odd number is 1. It's not supposed to keep finding subsequent odd numbers, or at least I don't see any indication of that in the OP.

Comment: lol dunno why but I thought it was supposed to keep getting the next odd number just by running it :D

Comment: b = b ^ 1 will work just fine. The inputs are small compared to max integer value.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry to accept another answer but hope you understand. You deserve the up votes.

Answer (score 8):

Not really shorter, but this is more legible:

```
a=5.4;
b=Math.ceil(a);
b = b % 2 ? b : b + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a = 5.4
b = Math.ceil(a)
b = b%2 == 0 ? b+1 : b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y = Math.ceil((x - 1)/2)*2  + 1
```

Execute fn on http://www.intmath.com/functions-and-graphs/graphs-using-jsxgraph.php

Answer (score 1):

Without `Math.ceil()` it can be done so:

```
b = a + a % 2 | 0 + 1;
```

**NB.** I consider next odd number of `5.0` as `7`.

Comment: Sorry, should have added the corner case from the beginning. Updated question. Keep this answer... unless you get down voted ;)